# ogr2ogr GDAL shapefile to KML info window

Tags: google-maps-api-3, esri, gdal

Running a GDAL command

```
 ogr2ogr -f "KML" test.kml test.shp
```

to convert a shapefile to a kml file. The issue I am having is that the info window is being converted into  tags which do not turn into info windows on KML. I can certainly parse through these files and create the new  tags with info pulled from SimpleData, but if this is possible on conversion it would be nice. Also the polygon seems to be missing its fill coming from Shapefile.

```
https://sites.google.com/site/gmaptest123/kml/test.kml?attredirects=0&d=1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample KML and perhaps a link to a generated KML file that exhibits the problem? (I'm assuming the complete KML will be too big/complex to post in your question)

Comment: attached. I dont know much about the shapefile resources but I have a number of other file s .prj, .sbn, .sbs, .shp.xml, .shx. When I rendered this inside of ESRI web I had to import all of these files in order to render a map properly. Maybe .shp contains the whole binary, I dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<PolyStyle>` in your KML is set to 0 if you change it to 1 it will fill.  The [PolyStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#polystyle) also lets you set the color and opacity of the polygon.

```
<Style>
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000ff</color>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <fill>0</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

For the data in the infowindows, you can add a `<name>` and `<description>` tag to each Placemark, that will appear in the infowindow.  If you have a lot of Polygons, doing that manually might be painful, not sure without looking at your input files why that didn't get generated automatically.

[your original polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=https://sites.google.com/site/gmaptest123/kml/test.kml?attredirects=0&d=1)

[my local copy](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_test_20140205.kml)

[with fill 1](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_test_20140205_fill1.kml)

Comment: I do have a lot of polygons but they are going to be in seperate files(~2000). Since I want to have roll over I will probably keep the KMLS as is and parse the KML to client side markers at runtime